# Append InputStream object to String object

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

I'm trying to append data from a InputStream object to a string as follows:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
InputStream stdout;
String s = "";      
while(IsMoreInputDataAvailable()) {
    int length = this.stdout.read(buffer);
    s += new String(this.buffer, 0, length, "ASCII");
```

Is there an easier way of doing this without using Apache or such libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way to read character data from an `InputStream` is to wrap it in a [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html). InputStreams are for binary data, Readers are for character data. The appropriate `Reader` to read from an `InputStream` is the aptly named [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html):

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(stdout, "ASCII");
char buf = new char[4096];
int length;
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
while ((length = r.read(buf)) != -1) {
    s.append(buf, 0, length);
}
String str = s.toString();
```

Note that appending to a `String` repeatedly inside a loop is usually a bad idea (because each time you'll need to copy the whole string), so I'm using a `StringBuilder` here instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [a link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ro/2012/08/convert-inputstream-to-string-java-example-tutorial.html) to several ways to do it (with and without external libraries).
A way to do it (extracted from the above link) is using a Java Scanner (since Java 5):

```
public class InputStreamTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:/sample.txt");
        String inputStreamString = new Scanner(fis,"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        System.out.println(inputStreamString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - i have improved the answer just now.